Spotfire package builder how to use code-signing service to sign our custom packages?
According to Spotfire package builder documentation, we should be able to use code-signing service like DegiCert to sign our custom packages ([https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-Sign-Custom-Extensions-Using-Spotfire-Package-Builder]):
*Package Builder Console: For enhanced security, use the Package Builder Console.
There are two options:

Install the certificate in the certificate store: Install the code-signing certificate directly into the certificate store on your build machine. Use the Spotfire Package Builder console with the "/localcert" parameter to reference the certificate.
Use a code-signing service: Opt for a code-signing service (e.g., DigiCert) that securely manages the private key, providing a more secure method for code-signing.*

But I could not find any documentation or example that describes what should be done to hook Package Builder console to code-sign DegiCert service.
Please advise if you have any clue on how to achieve the above.
The Package Builder help nor the provided examples (https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire_dev/area/doc/html/devdoc/topics/examples_of_building_using_the_package_builder_console.html) do provide any details about the usage of code-sign services
